# Finding a holomorphic bijection from $\Omega = \{z|\rm{Im}(z)>0\}\setminus\{i\}$ to $\Psi=\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find a holomorphic bijection from $\Omega = \{z|\rm{Im}(z)>0\}\setminus\{i\}$ to $\Psi=\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$.

I'm trying to solve this but honestly I'm kind of lost. It's easy to go from $\Omega$ to the entire plane but $i$ using $z^4$, but then it's not possible to map $i$ into the line segment $[0,1]$.

So I think I should map the bottom half of the plane into $(0,1]$ somehow and then map $i$ into $0$, but it can't be holomorphic on the bottom half of the plane since it's not an open map. So it must be holomorphic only on $\Omega$, maybe with $i$. I really have no idea how to find something like that though..

Comment: Not sure if this comment is helpful, but _a priori_ you do not map $i$ (or the bottom half-plane) to anywhere. You only need to prescribe where to map each point of $\Omega$, i.e. each point of the open upper half-plane _except_ the point $i$.

Comment: Start with looking what you get from $z \mapsto z^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer oops... I looked at it wrong apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Fischer's hint I realized I failed at considering the image after applying $z^2$  (or $z^4$ as can be seen in the question itself), actually if $f_1(z)=z^2$ then

$$f_1(\Omega) = \mathbb{C}\setminus(\{-1\}\cup[0,\infty])$$

where it would suffice to find a Mobious transformation mapping $$-1 \to\infty\\0\to0\\\infty\to1$$

which is given by
$$f_{2}\left(z\right)=\frac{z}{z+1}$$

hence the holomorphic $f$ is 
$$f\left(z\right)=f_2\circ f_1(z)=\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+1}$$